# Facebook reboots computer after several minutes

Tags: windows-7, memory, crash, facebook

Running Windows 7 Ultimate - 64 bit, any browser (I have several), 3.60 GHz, 16 GB RAM.
Whenever I access Facebook after several minutes it crashes the computer with a memory dump and reboots. I have ran a full virus scan and drives and memory and always keep the firewall active. I use Comodo Internet Security Premium when browsing and clear cache daily. This started over a month ago and only happens whenever I access Facebook. This is the ONLY program that is effected. Windows 7 is updated.

Answer (score 0):

You likely have malware. These 2 manual scan tools will probably get you up and running again.

[MalwareBytes](https://www.malwarebytes.com/) - (during installation don't activate the Free Pro Trial)

[AdwCleaner](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/adwcleaner/) - When using AdwCleaner, after the scan has finished, you MUST look through the scan results and uncheck any entries that you do not wish to remove.

If you don't feel comfortable doing this on your own, ask for help at [BleepingComputer's forums](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/)